# Trigger not firing for Multirow bulk Insert?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I have an after Insert trigger which is working fine when I am inserting a single record in a table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_Into_Questions_Table] 
ON  [dbo].[Questionmaster]
After Insert
AS 
BEGIN
Insert into Questions(Question_questionid,Question_questionname,Question_answer1,Question_answer2,Question_answer3,Question_answer4,Exam_examtypeid,User_Userid)
select Question_questionid,Question_questionname,Question_answer1,Question_answer2,Question_answer3,Question_answer4,Exam_examtypeid,User_Userid from Inserted
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

**Problem**:

When I am trying to Insert Multiple Records using BulkCopy from my C# code trigger is not working.

Comment: [Controlling Trigger Execution When Bulk Importing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the BULK INSERT statement do not execute triggers. However, you can enable triggers by using FIRE_TRIGGERS qualifiers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.105).aspx

SQL Server 2005 and later versions use row versioning for triggers and stores the row versions in the version store in tempdb. Before you can bulk import a large batch of data records using triggers, you may need to expand the size of tempdb to accommodate the impact of the triggers on the version store. For more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Where I need to use that BulkInsert statement.?

Comment: when you insert bulk data into this table how are you doing it?

Comment: I am using Sql BulkCopy method from my C# Code.

Comment: try this SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers

Comment: syntax: 
WITH (
  FIRE_TRIGGERS
)

Comment: using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers, null))

Answer (score -1):

Triggers are fired once per statement not per row on the database. So you need to change the way you are inserting bulk records.

Have a look at this msdn article
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx
that explains how to use triggers in Bulk insert.